# Convert HTML string to JavaScript text keeping indentation

Tags: javascript, komodoedit

I want to target or match only the first occurrence per line

Typical Scenario:

I have an HTML Structure that I am using in JavaScript.

```
<ul>
    <li> ABC </li>
    <li> DEF </li>
    <li> GHI <span> GHI-SPAAN </span> </li>
</ul>
```

To convert the above into a string, in my editor, I can simply Find & replace EOL with a `'+`
and beginning of line with a `'` so that the code would be

```
var tpl = ''+
    '<ul> '+
    '<li> ABC </li> '+
    '<li> DEF </li> '+
    '<li> GHI <span> GHI-SPAAN </span> </li> '+
    '</ul> ';
```

But you see, I **loose the indentation** when I replace the beginning of line with `'<`

So I want to uniquely target (target only the first occurrence of `<` and replace with `'<` )

I am using KOMODO edit and Sublime Text 2

Comment: What is wrong with `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Who cares about the indentation of markup that is inside a string anyway?

Comment: @Blender, Oops! Sorry for not being clear. I want to store some HTML in a variable (not taken from DOM, I am gonna create it). I want to copy paste it from some HTML file and save myself, the typing efforts

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I want to keep the indentation so that it looks good to the one who reads code, and follow the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a KomodoEdit user, but I tried these replacements and they worked:

- starting quote: replace `^(\s*)<` with `\1<`
- ending quote: replace `>\s*$` with `>' +`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The **`\1`** was what I was looking for - It **keeps** your matches. Thanks for showing understanding ability - he he

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting HTML to a JS string, it would be much better to create the elements in JS and put them in the DOM. This would give you much more control, not create such a difficult to maintain/read code, and be much faster (amongst other benefits):

```
var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
outerDiv.className = "spa-shell-head";

var innerDivLogo = document.createElement("div");
innerDivLogo.className = "spa-shell-head-logo";

var innerDivAcct = document.createElement("div");
innerDivAcct.className = "spa-shell-head-acct";

var innerDivSearch = document.createElement("div");
innerDivSearch.className = "spa-shell-head-search";

outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivLogo);
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivAcct);
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivSearch);
document.body.appendChild(outerDiv);
```

The above creates the following:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yfeLbhe4/

Comment: That was only an example, the main question was to maintain indentation.

Comment: @OmShankar Why would you wish to maintain indentation?

Comment: Single page apps, templates. Scala map methods. XML fragments, YAML configuration, etc.

Comment: @OmShankar Why not write something that reformats the code before it's displayed? Much less likely to produce errors in formatting if it's not left up to the user.

Comment: you didn't get my comment. I just wanted to say that in a normal day to day coding (including back end) you need indentation, not just HTML files. Now if you do find-and-replace like the example I gave above, you would loose indentation in the code file. So there should be a way to maintain the formatting of any code after such operation. Which is something I found in the answer.