# Converting HTML to JavaScript string in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm

I'd like to convert some html easily into concatenated JS strings in PhpStorm.

From:

```html
<div class="spa-shell-head">
  <div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>
  <div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>
  <div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>
</div>
```

To:

```js
var main_html = ''
+ '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
+ '  <div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
+ '  <div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>'
+ '  <div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>'
+ '</div>';
```

Ideally into the other direction as well. Is there any chance to achieve this? With a plugin? I could imagine that a macro with some regex could do it. Is it possbile?

Same question for other IDE can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516154/convert-html-to-javascript-string). Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310279/convert-html-string-to-javascript-text-keeping-indentation).

Comment: This will work , are you facing any problem?

Comment: use mustachejs and forget about code inlining in JS https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/288977/8779228/a3cf700e-2f02-11e5-869a-300312fb7a00.gif

Comment: This is really not good practice. It's much better to create the elements in JS and insert them into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Using only PHPStorm, you can use the [Extra Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213) plugin:

- Select all your lines
- Split the selection into lines (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)
- Go to the beginning of the line (<kbd>home</kbd>)
- Add a plus sign and a quote
- Go to the end of the line (<kbd>end</kbd>)
- Add a quote

Comment: The second step is why the plugin is required. Can be also done with the mouse when this plugin isn't installed (Column selection mode in Edit menu).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting HTML to a JS string, you should really create your elements in JS and then insert them into the DOM. This would give you much more control, not create such a difficult to maintain/read code, cause less problems, and be much faster to boot:

```
var outerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a div
outerDiv.className = "spa-shell-head"; // Give it a class

var innerDivLogo = document.createElement("div");
innerDivLogo.className = "spa-shell-head-logo";

var innerDivAcct = document.createElement("div");
innerDivAcct.className = "spa-shell-head-acct";

var innerDivSearch = document.createElement("div");
innerDivSearch.className = "spa-shell-head-search";

outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivLogo); // Append into original div
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivAcct);
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDivSearch);

document.body.appendChild(outerDiv); // Add to page
```

The above creates the following:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yfeLbhe4/

Comment: The HTML is more readable than the JS code, IMO. I would consider this if I get performance issues.